# How to programmatically upload and download any file on Google Drive in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, database-backups, google-drive-android-api

I have created an application in Android studio which store users information and other data in sqlite database. I want to give user an option to create the backup of their data(upload the database.db file) on Google Drive and restore (download the database.db file) from Google Drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[here](https://github.com/prof18/Database-Backup-Restore) is a perfect example for what you need. Go through the project and you will be able to do backup/restore of your db.

Comment: DriveClient and DriveResourceClient are deprecated. That solution seems to be old, needs to be migrated to rest API

Comment: Hii.. Do you have any idea how to backup a folder of an app which is created on device??